# Weierstrass substitution on an algebraic expression

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, substitution

I start with the trigonometric equation $3\tan{2x} + 16\cot^2{x} = 0$, although there is a particular solution pathway that I can follow by taking the double-angle identity to reduce the LHS to a cubic expression in terms of $\tan{x}$, I'm curious on a particular line of reasoning that follows by substituting $t = \tan(\frac{x}{2})$, and substituting the typical expressions after applying $$\tan{2x} = \frac{2\tan{x}}{1 - \tan^2{x}},~~\cot^2{x} = \frac{1}{\tan^2{x}},$$ where $\tan{x} = \frac{2t}{1-t^2}$.

My two questions posed are:

(a) Is the Weierstrass substitution here valid in this context of manipulating trigonometric equations algebraically?

(b) If so, is this particular case worthwhile trying to solve using such a substitution?

*Post-note:* A better question would be whether such substitutions are even well-formed in algebra, there is the constraint that $0 \leq x \leq \pi$, so I would've presumed there'd be no conflicts between domains/ranges if that is even a consideration.

Comment: (a) Yes, as long as you're careful about discarding extraneous solutions. (b) Eh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Weierstrass substitution is *always* valid in whatever you're doing, be it integrating tricky trigonometric integrals or solving trig equations (eg the one you're solving). This is because the Weierstrass substitution $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ relies on *identities*, and identities are by definition always true.

However, as noted in the comments, the Weierstrass substitution can introduce extra solutions into the equation we are solving given the constraints you are dealing with, so if you use it always doublecheck if the solutions you obtained make sense.

In this particular case, without using the Weierstrass substitution we have the cubic equation
$$\frac{6\tan x}{1-\tan^2 x}+\frac{16}{\tan^2x}=0\iff3\tan^3x-8\tan^2x+8=0$$
By using the factor theorem and trying small values for $\tan x$, I quite quickly saw that $\tan x=2$ is a solution and therefore $\tan x-2$ is a factor of our expression. Hence, our expression is equivalent to
$$(\tan x-2)(3\tan^2x-2\tan x-4)=0$$
And the second factor is just a quadratic in $\tan x$ which we can solve easily.

So, all in all, in this case my personal preference would be not to use the Weierstrass substitution; it would've complicated an expression which turned out to be rather nice.

On the other hand, eg if we had the equation $3\sin x+2\cos x-9=0$ then the Weierstrass substitution is very useful if we don't want to resort to the $R\cos(x+\alpha)$ and $R\sin(x+\alpha)$ formulae (indeed I very rarely want to resort to them). In general, if we have the equation $a\sin x+b\cos x+c=0$ then I always recommend using the Weierstrass substitution, unless it's something really simple.

---

I hope that was helpful. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Excellent! I'm in A-level just like you and this question came up and I was entirely reaching for solutions. This clarifies the solution very well. Thanks!

Comment: @клйкбаутоьмажазвайкукас Wow, it's great to meet a fellow A Level student on here! :) Believe me, you can learn SO much from this site, I really recommend asking anything you like on here. I take it that you're doing Maths and Further Maths A Levels then?

Comment: Yep, fast-track regular/further mathematics, so I'm always spending my spare-time studying mathematics, but this question stumped me unnecessarily hard on top of my poor sleeping schedule. In any case, thank you for your answer, always nice to meet peers.

Comment: @клйкбаутоьмажазвайкукас You're really welcome! By the way, would you like an integration challenge? You should find it very stimulating.

Comment: In my experience, the term 'Weierstrass substitution' is only used in the context of integration, not solving trigonometric equations. And in the context of integration, it is only valid when integrating a rational function of trigonometric functions.

Comment: Feel free to send the challenge! And @Joe yep, that's pretty much my question, thanks!

Comment: @клйкбаутоьмажазвайкукас: You can still let $t=\tan(x/2)$ when trying to solve a trigonometric equation. I was just making a minor linguistic point—that the term Weierestrass substitution is generally only used in the context of integration.

Comment: @клйкбаутоьмажазвайкукас find $$\int\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}dx$$ *without* the Weierstrass substitution. Good luck! Tell me how you do.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Spent a lot of time on this, but I just divided the fraction top-and-bottom by $\frac{1}{\sin{x}}$ and solved $\frac{1}{1 + \cot{x}}$ by letting $u = \tan{x}$, solving the partial fraction and going from there. Is that valid?

Comment: @клйкбаутоьмажазвайкукас that's a very nice method and perfectly valid, I didn't think of that method. The way I know is different though.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you! I'm just wondering, why did you only see this question now? Did it come up as an active question?

Comment: Yes I have seen your question now after your edit. You can see my login in MSE.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution is perfectly valid, but it can *miss* some solutions. If we consider
$$
\tan2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}\tag{*}
$$
we see that the left-hand side is defined for $x=\pi/2$, whereas the right-hand side isn't. Same problem for $x=3\pi/2$. The right-hand side is also undefined for $x=\pi/4+k\pi$ and $x=3\pi/4+k\pi$, but so isn't the left-hand side as well.

Thus, when you apply the identity to an equation, you also have to consider the possibly missed solutions. In your case, $x=\pi/2+k\pi$ *is* a solution!

But you may also multiply numerator and denominator the right-hand side in (*) by $\cot^2x$ so obtaining
$$
\tan2x=\frac{2\cot x}{\cot^2x-1}\tag{**}
$$
which isn't free from the same issue, because $x=k\pi$ makes the right-hand side invalid. However, in the particular case, this is not of a concern, because the equation also contains $\cot x$.

Upon applying the identity (**), you get
$$
\frac{6\cot x}{\cot^2x-1}+16\cot^2x=0
$$
and you can factor out $2\cot x$, after observing that it gives the solutions $x=\pi/2+k\pi$.

Thus the equation becomes
$$
3+8\cot^3x-8\cot x=0
$$
that factors as
$$
(2\cot x-1)(4\cot^2x+2\cot x-3)=0
$$

Comment: I'm agree with you. +1.